# Find the distinct user in SQL Server Table Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Find the distinct user where he has logged in all the months from the given date
has to be the current date, not consider the month.

Only the current date. Not current month

Find the distinct users who logged I every month

From the example, 
Aditya and Kumar logged in Jan. Feb, Mar, Apr so they are called as repeated users

So I need count as 2

New User: If a user logged in only only the latest week and never before is called as new user

Ex: Gopal is called as a new user as he logged only on April 26 and 28

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker](
 [SNo] [nchar](10) NULL,
 [Username] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [LoginDate] [datetime2](7) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'1 ', N'Adhitya', CAST(N'2020-01-12T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'2 ', N'Selvam', CAST(N'2020-01-01T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'3 ', N'Kumar', CAST(N'2020-02-02T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'4 ', N'Adhitya', CAST(N'2020-02-02T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'5 ', N'Selvam', CAST(N'2020-02-12T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'6 ', N'Kumar', CAST(N'2020-02-02T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'7 ', N'Adhitya', CAST(N'2020-03-17T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'8 ', N'Selvam', CAST(N'2020-03-23T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'9 ', N'Kumar', CAST(N'2020-03-23T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'10', N'Kumar', CAST(N'2020-03-27T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'11', N'Kumar', CAST(N'2020-04-02T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'12', N'Kumar', CAST(N'2020-04-15T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'13', N' pal', CAST(N'2020-04-26T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'14', N' pal', CAST(N'2020-04-28T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'15', N'Adhitya', CAST(N'2020-04-28T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
 
INSERT [dbo].[dbo.usagetracker] ([SNo], [Username], [LoginDate]) VALUES (N'16', N'Kumar', CAST(N'2020-01-15T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Updated with SQL Table script. Sorry for the Inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select username
from t
where logindate >= @date
group by username
having count(distinct year(logindate) * 100 + month(logindate)) = datediff(month, @date, logindate) + 1;
```

Actually, you can simplify that `having` clause to:

```
having count(distinct eomonth(logindate)) = datediff(month, @date, logindate) + 1;
```